# adding length to 'slide' 'left'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm wondering how to edit the amount of direction the div will slide to the left. Thus far I'm only editing the 'tween' or 'slide' effect, and I'd like the slide out to go for `500px;` and the stop.

http://jsfiddle.net/7m7uK/523/

```
$('#loginPanel').ready(function() {

                if ($('#userNav').is(':hidden')) {

                   $('#userNav').show('slide',{direction:'left'},5000);
                }    
});
```

Comment: why don't you use .animate, with show it will slide till its width as given in CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way would be to `animate` the `margin` by the required number of `pixels`

```
$("element").animate({marginLeft : "-20px"}, 500);
```

NOTE: `"slide"` will generally be for the complete `width/height` of the element. You can try to set the `distance` parameter, but it will not give you the effect that you want.

```
     <script>
      $("#hide").click(function(){
         $(".target").hide( "slide", 
                     { direction: "down" ,
                       distance: "200px" }, 2000 );
      });

      $("#show").click(function(){
         $(".target").show( "slide", 
                      {direction: "up" }, 2000 );
      });



      });
       </script>
       <style>
          p {
               background-color:#bca;
               width:200px; 
               border:1px solid green; 
            }
         div{ width:100px; 
                height:100px; 
                background:red;  
            }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>

   <p>Click on any of the buttons</p>
   <button id="hide"> Hide </button>
   <button id="show"> Show</button> 

   <div class="target">
   </div>
```